# Can't boot Windows 10 with SSD M.2 connected – Auto repair

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, uefi

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 7559.
Last night, I added a V-NAND SSD 850 EVO with a 500 GB capacity, where I planned to clone my current 1 TB HDD (with only 264 GB used).

I plugged it in, and booted normally. When trying to clone it with Samsung's cloning software, the app became unresponsive and then exited by itself without issuing an error. As I wasn't sure if it had been cloned, I tried to reboot.

Since then, I can't boot with my SSD plugged in, even if I try to boot from the HDD.
I tried adding new boot options, but they won't work.

The HDD alone boots just fine.
As soon as I try to boot with the SSD connected, it will start the Auto repair.

BIOS sees both disks, and if I go to the command prompt and issue the diskpart command, I see both disks, with the SSD being empty.

How can I do to boot with both drives connected, so I can clone it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that the cloning gone bad screwed some things.

From command line, with diskpart I noticed that the SSD wasn't GPT, so I converted it with that same tool. In addition to that, I created EFI and MSR partitions (not sure if that was necessary but I was following a tutorial and did that anyways). That did the trick and allowed me to boot into my HDD normally.

Now I'm trying to clone the disk again.

Thanks for taking a look into it!

Answer (score 0):

Boot the pc without the SSD, create a Gparted bootable usb, boot Gparted with the SSD plugged in and try to format it

Comment: Formatting it with the diskpart would work? Should format the entire dirve into NTFS?

Answer (score 0):

I think actually booting from HDD and ending with auto-repair kicking in, MIGHT only happen, when you have cloned the drive and both of them have the same ID. Otherwise I don't see a way it could happen.

Please do the following (you will need an USB drive that can be made bootable):

1. Disconnect SSD
2. Download software called Macrium Reflect FREE (free version available for private use) [Macrium Reflect site](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree)
3. Install, create Rescue Media on the thumbdrive [image]
4. Swap disks and boot from thumbdrive
5. When booted, select command prompt from the taskbar, there you will have access to DISKPART, use it to CLEAN the SSD.
6. Connect the other disk, boot from thumbdrive and use macrium reflect to clone the disks

To think of it, you could actually try booting from the rescue-thumbdrive with two disks connected and letting me know how that went, it should not call up the auto-restore...